# How to connect memcached with spring MVC API to get and set data

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, memcached, spymemcached

I am new to memcached and Spring MVC, I am trying to create a rest api which would be setting some values in memcached. Which I can retrieve also.
But I am not getting the right way to connect to memcached.

Consumerconfiguration:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;   import com.btmatthews.springboot.memcached.EnableMemcached;

@EnableMemcached
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "msg91.consumers.consumer")
public class consumerConfiguration {

}
```

ConsumerInitializer class :

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class consumerInitializer  extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { consumerConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

Controller class:

```
@RestController
public class consumerController {
    @Autowired
    private MemcachedClient memcachedClient;

    @RequestMapping(value="/queues/{queueName}/thread-counts/{threadCount}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void setThreadCount(@PathVariable String queueName, @PathVariable int threadCount) {
        System.out.println("Queue name is "+queueName);
        System.out.println("Thread count is "+threadCount);     
        memcachedClient.set(queueName, 0, threadCount);//Setting the values in memcache which I get in api
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/queues/{queueName}/thread-counts", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getThreadCount(@PathVariable String queueName) {
        System.out.println("Queue value is"+queueName);
        int threadCount = (Integer)memcachedClient.get(queueName);
        System.out.println("Thread count for " + queueName + " is " + threadCount);
    }
}
```

Spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<bean name="defaultMemcachedClient" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
  <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
  </property>
  <property name="addressProvider">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
 <property name="address" value="127.0.0.1:11211" />
  </bean>
  </property>
```

It is not working, giving error:

Servlet [spring-dispatcher] in web application [/consumer-api] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet

I think I am not able to give the path of memcache properly or not able to connect to memcached.
Please help me to resolve this issue.